# SolrNET localParams (for tagging filterQuery) cause exception with multiple values

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am trying to implement localParams in a SolrNET implementation but running into problems when we try to prefix a field with the localParams in a query with multiple values.

We are trying to use localParams for tagging and excluding filters. See: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters for more information.

To achieve this we need to tag the filterQuery for our filter/facet field (referred to as field_name below) and exclude the tag in our facetField. The facetField exclusion of a tag works perfectly but we are having problems with the filterQuery when multiple values are selected.

I have found the difference in the generated query string to be the following:

Without localParams:

```
fq=field_name:"value1,value2"
```

With localParams:

```
fq=({!paramKey=paramValue}field_name:"value1" OR {!paramKey=paramValue}field_name:"value2")
```

Expected:

```
fq={!paramKey=paramValue}field_name:"value1,value2"
```

We are initiating the Solr query with a call to: `SolrInstance.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions options)` and the filter query affected by this issue can be found in the `QueryOptions.FilterQueries` collection as defined below:

```
SolrNet.SolrQueryInList
    .FieldName: {!paramKey=paramValue}field_name
    .List
        .string[]
            "value1",
            "value2"
```

The localParam(s) has/have been prefixed with the `.FieldName` property. This doesn't work, presumably because Solr doesn't recognise `{!paramKey=paramValue}field_name` as a valid FieldName and this seems to be why the exception is thrown.

Can anyone provide any advise on how to implement localParams for SolrNET without getting this issue. The implementation works fine for single values but throws the exception below for multiple values:

```
[SolrNet.Exceptions.InvalidFieldException] = {"Bad Request"}
```

We are using the following versions:
SolrNET: v0.3.0
Solr: v4.3.0

The code for applying the localParams to our filterQueries can be found below:

```
foreach (var filterQuery in parameters.FilterQuery)
{
    if (parameters.LocalParams.Any(x => x.Field == filterQuery.Field && x.QueryType == QueryType.Filter))
    {
        var valueDictionary = parameters.LocalParams.Where(x => x.QueryType == QueryType.Filter && x.Field == filterQuery.Field).ToDictionary(param => param.Action, param => param.Value);

        filterQuery.Field = new SolrQuery(new LocalParams(valueDictionary) + filterQuery.Field).Query;
    }
}
```

The above code iterates over filterQueries and prefixes the .Field with the localParams syntax.

Comment: Comma-separated value are incorrect here. See http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/seeley-solr-facetseurocon2011/28 https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying#Query_by_list_of_values

Comment: Also I recommend not relying on mutating any SolrNet objects. They will eventually all be immutable.